# JBoss: Application keeps running but logging stops

Tags: jboss

We have an application in production.
Logs are suffixed with the date.
When I look at the sizes of the logs, I notice that some of them are less than 1 KB with the following contents:

```
16:54:44,497 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.exceptions.ObjectStoreException: ShadowingStore::read_state err$
16:54:44,538 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA012154: RecoverAtomicAction: transaction 0:ffff0ab2c460:5954aed8:558ecf50:989db$
16:54:44,540 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA012155: RecoverAtomicAction - tried to move failed activation log 0:ffff0ab2c46$
16:54:44,541 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.exceptions.ObjectStoreException: ShadowingStore::read_state err$
16:54:44,544 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA012154: RecoverAtomicAction: transaction 0:ffff0ab2c460:5954aed8:558ecf50:989d2$
16:54:44,545 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA012155: RecoverAtomicAction - tried to move failed activation log 0:ffff0ab2c46$
16:59:04,549 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.exceptions.ObjectStoreException: ShadowingStore::read_state err$
16:59:04,552 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA012154: RecoverAtomicAction: transaction 0:ffff0ab2c460:5954aed8:558ecf50:98ef3$
16:59:04,553 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA012155: RecoverAtomicAction - tried to move failed activation log 0:ffff0ab2c46$
```

I am definite that:

- The application was up and running all the time.
- The application was doing a lot of work (It is not possible to have empty logs)
- Other full log files do not contain these lines (com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.exceptions.ObjectStoreException)

I also remark that:

- The time of the logs is 16:54 which means that even if an exception stopped the logging, we should have previous logs.
- Apparently, this might be a bug but according to some issues I found, the whole application stops.

Comment: What specific version of JBoss are you using? Best add the tag for the specific version and edit the version in your question.